# Problema con formato de fecha al transcribirlo a casilla con VBA - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy trabajando en una macro en la cual a través de un formulario y un cuadro de texto llamado `fechasolicitudreq`. Estoy guardando las fechas en las celdas correspondientes.

He probado los siguientes formatos:

- `Cells(i,j).Value = Me.fechasolicitudreq.Value`
- `Cells(i,j).Value = Format(Me.fechasolicitudreq.Value, "Short Date")`
- `Cells(i,j).Value = Format(Me.fechasolicitudreq.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Pero me ocurre lo siguiente:

- Si fecha es **10/01/2017** en la casilla se escribe  **1/10/2017**
- Si fecha es **13/01/2017** en la casilla se escribe  **13/01/2017**

Es más, el gran dilema es que además los resultados de las funciones `Month()` y `Day()` también se ven afectados. Por pruebas realizadas, se asigna el `dd` como **día** si este es mayor que **12**, pero sino, se asigna como **mes** (y eso se aprecia en las funciones).

Ojalá pudiera darle el formato de fecha en español, pero en el caso de que no, al menos que las funciones `Day()` y `Month()` sean coherentes, para poder usar esa información.

Nota: He intentado también concatenar un string vacío, pero lo cambia automáticamente a `date`.

Answer (score 3):

Probaste dándole el formato a la misma celda?
En **Formato de Celda** / **Número** / **Personalizada**
y verificas que la casilla tenga el formato **dd/mm/yyyy** tal vez tiene el formato **d/mm/yyyy**.

Comment: No había probado eso, sin embargo, es al ponerlo en formato EEUU que se ve como debería en la casilla, pero al hacer pruebas y pedirle   Day()  en un caso me lo considera 1 (10/01/2017)  y en el otro me lo considera 13 (13/01/2017).   O sea que al ingresarlo no reconoce el formato  dd/mm/yyyy , asigna el día solo si es mayor que 12. Sino, se invierte y el resultado de funciones Month y Day también cambia

Comment: Y si vas al Panel de Control de Windows, Fecha y Hora, Cambiar Fecha y Hora, Cambiar Configuración del Calendario, y revisas el formato de la fecha.

Comment: Ahí me sale  d/M/aaaa cambié  a dd/mm/aaaa y sigue entregando  los valores cambiados  las funciones u.u   Probé usando  "#" & fecha & "#" al menos ahí me la deja tal cuál, y programaré la función día, mes y año no más. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con esto, espero que te funcione:

1. Pasa la fecha en formato número:

   ```
   cells(i, j) = CDbl(CDate(fechasolicitudreq))
   ```
2. Cambia el formato en la hoja:

   ```
   cells(i, j).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está pasando es que un dato de fecha lo estás convirtiendo a texto y al pasarlo a Excel, este lo interpreta siguiendo sus propios algoritmos para ello en lo cual interviene la configuración regional del equipo del usuario. Lo mejor sería que pasaras un objeto de fecha y que usaras las opciones de formato de número de la celda para mostrar el dato en la forma que lo deseas.

Información adicional:

De acuerdo a [Tipos de datos Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/gg278460(v=office.15).aspx) (énfasis mío)

> Las variables Date muestran fechas según el formato corto de fecha **reconocido por el equipo**. Las horas se muestran según el formato de hora (de 12 horas o de 24 horas) **reconocido por el equipo**.

para entender que es lo que está pasando, lo habría  que hacer es conocer la configuración regional de tu equipo, sin embargo, como la configuración de cada equipo puede variar y en un mismo equipo puede variar de un momento a otro, el uso del formato corto resulta muy poco conveniente.

Answer (score 1):

Me pasó lo mismo, del día 1 al 12 me importaba las fechas con formato fecha internacional y del 13 en adelante como fecha tradicional. Lo solucioné Declarando la variable como Date.

```
    Dim fecha as Date
    fecha = Me.fechasolicitudreq.Value
    Cells(i,j) = fecha
```

Answer (score 0):

A mí me ocurría lo mismo. Debes pasar el formato de los datos de las celdas a "Texto" para que interprete correctamente las fechas. Hazlo así (para 31 filas y en la segunda columna, por ejemplo):

```
For i = 1 To 31
    With Worksheets(NombreHoja)
        .Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
    End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

estuve con el mismo problema. en un principio tenia una variabla ' fecha '  que la defini como Publica en un modulo. y comenzó tarbajando bien. pero luego defini en la misma línea otra variable publica ' Fecha_est '. y ahi dejo de funcionar 'fecha' me cargaba la fecha en la hoja con el fomato mm/dd/yy.

lo solucione definiedo en lineas separadas en el modulo 1 las 2 variables
'
Public fecha As Date
Public fecha_est As Date
'
saludos

Answer (score 0):

**MÉTODO 1**
Haciendo pruebas he descubierto que con un simple ***Replace(.Text, "/", "/")*** la celda hace un swap con mm/dd/yyyy <-> dd/mm/aaaa.

El código queda así:

```
Sub BotonFormateaFecha_Click()

    'Obligatorio si no queremos que recorra la columna entera
    Range("AG2", "AG" & Range("AG1").End(xlDown).Row).Select

    'Swap mm/dd/yyyy <-> dd/mm/aaaa
    For Each obj_cell In Selection.Cells
        With obj_cell
            If IsNull(obj_cell) Then Exit Sub
            .Value = Replace(.Text, "/", "/")
            '.NumberFormat = "dddd dd/mm/yyyy"
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque el codigo hace un swap dada vez que se ejecuta no lo hará en la línea 7 ya que se interpreta que la primera cifra es el día. Esto es en función de la configuracion de tu windows.

También podemos formatear la linea con

```
.NumberFormat = "dddd dd/mm/yyyy"
```

para obtener algo asi: *jueves 10/01/2019*

**MÉTODO 2**
Este es otro método y solo utiliza `Range.TextToColumns` junto con `FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)` como argumento.

Es increíble pero se queda solo en una línea. Además la celda no solo se queda formateada en fecha sino que admite cualquier carácter como separador de fechas. Lo bueno de esta simple línea es que nos evitamos utilizar operadores de asignación (**=**) o bucles o Replaces...
Después de ejecutarla todo el rango habrá cambiado al formato marcado por ***xlDMYFormat***.

Cuidado porque no es un formateo permanente. Si volvemos a escribir en esa celda con los métodos anteriores la celda volverá a mostrar el formato MDY.

```
'VBA Excel

'Copiamos A a C
Range("C1:C9") = Range("A1:A9").Value

'Cambiamos todo al formato marcado por xlDMYFormat
Range("C1:C9").TextToColumns FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlDMYFormat)
```

Ejemplo de caracteres admitidos y resultado final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro método consiste en formatear las celdas en modo texto, seleccionar solo el rango limitado y hacer un ***For Each***. Por supuesto los signos de ***Replace(.Text, ".", "-")*** pueden ser cambiados.

Este código funciona perfectamente.

```
'VBA Excel

Private Sub f_MiFuncion()

    'Obligatorio si no queremos que recorra la columna entera
    Range("E1", "E" & Range("E1").End(xlDown).Row).Select

    'Obligatorio para que Excel no haga swap ddmm->mmdd
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"

    'Este método no genera errores de swap
    For Each obj_cell In Selection.Cells
        With obj_cell
            If IsNull(obj_cell) Then Exit Sub
            obj_cell.Value = Replace(.Text, ".", "-")
        End With
    Next
   'Volvemos a formatear como Fecha
    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy;@"
End
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema y probé muchísimas cosas. Aclaro que no soy programador. Lo pude resolver haciendo lo siguiente:

1° defino una variable como fecha por ejemplo:

```
Dim Variablefecha As Date
```

2° a esa variable le incorporo la fecha necesaria (año, mes, día) con la función "DateSerial"

```
Variablefecha=DateSerial(2020,10,04)
```

Acá se pueden hacen referencias a otras variables o campos de un formulario. De hecho, yo traigo la información desde distintos campos de formularios.

3°Este es el paso más importante. Dado que tenemos la variable guardada como Date, al meterla en la hoja de cálculo, la celda debe tener formato de fecha (en mi caso le puse fecha corta, "dd/mm/aaaa") y con la función "Cdate" le vuelvo a dar formato de fecha y el código quedaría asi:

```
Hoja1.Range("A2")=Cdate(Variablefecha)
```

Puede ser redundante el trabajo con varias veces el formato de fecha, pero esto me resolvió el problema. Ojala le sirva a alguien.

Resumido quedaría algo asi:

```
Dim Variablefecha As Date
Variablefecha=DateSerial(2020,10,04)
Hoja1.Range("A2")=Cdate(Variablefecha)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Worksheet1.Cells(3, 4) = CDate(Date1).ToOADate
```

Comment: Saludos, te invito a revisar la sección [¿Cómo responder?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), para poder proporcionar información que ayude tanto al miembro que pregunta como a los miembros que revisan las publicaciones, sigue adelante ;).

Comment: Si bien este línea de código puede resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta, es mejor incluir una explicación de por qué lo hace. Las respuestas que son únicamente código son consideradas de baja calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema y le encontré la solución:

Antes que cargue la fecha cambiar el formato para que cuando se copie tenga el formato `dd/mm/yyyy`:

```
TextBox1.Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Luego en la celda consiguiente utilizar la función:

```
=TEXTO(B2;"dd/mm/yy")
```

Espero que sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema, para el primer caso se resuelve multiplicando por uno, para que se convierta en numero y luego le doy formato de fecha.

Cells(i,j).Value = Me.fechasolicitudreq.Value * 1

Cells(i,j).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Te comparto un método sencillo

```
Range("A1").Value = Format(TextBox1.Value, "*MM/DD/YYYY")
```

Con esto el valor en la celda A1 quedara correctamente "DD/MM/AAAA"